# Как слушать аутентификацию в Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

Необходимо после аутентификации с помощью Spring Security сбегать в бд и забрать оттуда служебные данные для сессии пользователя, как можно слушать этот момент кроме того, чтобы самому аутентифицировать пользователя в контроллере?

Comment: Попробуйте так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18127973/3212712

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я уже нашёл handler, в xml конфигурации можно указать ссылку на свой AuthenticationHandler реализующий соответствующий интерфейс, но все равно Спасибо. У меня терь другой вопрос, где я могу получить сессию Spring для данного пользователя  чтобы в неё положить тот объект

Comment: Попробуйте так: `Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё делается достаточно просто, создаётся класс реализующий интерфейс `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`, у него реализуется 1 метод

`onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication)`, в котором уже можно выполнять все необходимые операции,

например положить в сессию данные того самого пользователя:

```
    @Component
public class AuthHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {


    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        httpServletRequest.getSession().setAttribute("user", new User("vasya", "pupkin"));
        httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/user");

    }
}
```

Также, чтобы Spring Security вызывал его, необходимо в xml конфигурации дать ссылку на этот бин:

```
<form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="authHandler"/>
```

аналогично с java конфигурацией.